# SQL query to efficiently select non-perfect duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-10

I have a database table in the entity-attribute-value format which looks like this:

[image: radiology table]

I wish to select all rows that have the same values for the 'entity' and 'attribute' columns, but have different values for the 'value' column. Multiple rows with the same values for all three columns should be treated as a single row. The way I achieved this is by using SELECT DISTINCT.

```
SELECT entity_id, attribute_name, COUNT(attribute_name) AS NumOcc 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM radiology) x 
GROUP BY entity_id,attribute_name 
HAVING COUNT(attribute_name) > 1
```

[Response for this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL90m.png)

However, I have read that using SELECT DISTINCT is quite costly. I plan on using this query on very large tables, I am looking for a way to optimize this query, perhaps without using SELECT DISTINCT.

I am using PostgreSQL 10.3

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
from    radiology r
join    (
        select  entity_id
        ,       attribute_name
        from    radiology
        group by
                entity_id
        ,       attribute_name
        having  count(distinct value) > 1
        ) dupe
 on     r.entity_id = dupe.entity_id
        and r.attribute_name = dupe.attribute_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
select a.* from radiology a join 
(select entity, attribute, count(distinct value) cnt
from radiology 
group by entity, attribute
having count(distinct value)>1)b
on a.entity=b.entity and a.attribute=b.attribute
```

Comment: This is doing the same thing as Gordon's answer. Perhaps I didn't phrase my question well enough :^). I am looking to resolve the two "perfect duplicate" rows to a single row.

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to select all rows that have the same values for the 'entity' and 'attribute' columns, but have different values for the 'value' column.

Your method does not do this.  I would think `exists`:

```
select r.*
from radiology r
where exists (select 1
              from radiology r2
              where r2.entity = r.entity and r2.attribute = r.attribute and
                    r2.value <> r.value
             );
```

If you just want the entity/attribute values with pairs, use `group by`:

```
select entity, attribute
from radiology
group by entity, attribute
having min(value) <> max(value);
```

Note that you *could* use `having count(distinct value) > 1`, but `count(distinct)` incurs more overhead than `min()` and `max()`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `r2.value <> r.value` in the first query?

Comment: This solution pulls the "perfect duplicate" rows (10 and 11 in the example image) rather than just one. The intention is to have two duplicate rows resolve to one row.

Comment: @NoahRoseLedesma . . . And the second query should do that.